# Python MVC - trying to assign data from sqlite database into tkinter label widgets

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, model-view-controller, pycharm

How I can attach data from sqlite database into widget in tkinter, for example Label? Currently, I have working database, with some dummy data, but I actually can't assign any of it to Labels in View, to present it to the user. Here's some code:

*Model class*

```
def display_all_employees(self):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("employees_database.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
    SELECT name FROM employees
    """)

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

*Controller*

```
class Controller:
    test_str = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View(self)
        self.employee_database = Database()

    def main(self):
        self.employee_database.create_database()
        self.view.main()

    def display_all_employees_data(self):
        self.model.display_all_employees(self.test_str)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    calculator = Controller()
    calculator.main()
```

*View*

```
class View(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Calculator")
        self.controller = controller
        self._make_main_frame()
        self._make_buttons()
        self._center_window()

    def _make_main_frame(self):
        self.main_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.main_frame.pack()

        btn = ttk.Button(text="print")
        btn.pack()
```

Comment: If there is only one column `name` is retrieved from database, you can use `Listbox` widget to show them.

Comment: There's a little more columns. I just wanted to retrieve any data from it. My problem is that I don't know how I should give data from model to controller, and then to the view.

Comment: You can return the result records from `model.display_all_employees()`, then `controller` can pass it to `view`.

Comment: That's why I posted this question. I've spend a couple hours trying to figure it out - I don't know how to pass data from db to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is for your function to return the data that needs to be sent to the view. Since the function is being called by the controller, the controller can then take the result and pass it to the view.

```
class Model:
    ...
    def display_all_employees(self):
        ...
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        ...
        return rows

class Controller:
    ...
    def display_all_employees_data(self):
        rows = self.model.display_all_employees(self.test_str)
        self.view.update_all_employees(rows)

class View(tk.Tk):
    ...
    def update_all_employees(self, rows):
        ...
```

In this case, however, I would rename `display_all_employees` to `get_all_employees` since the model isn't responsible for displaying anything, it' just responsible for getting the data.

---

Another way would be to add a method to the controller for sending the data to a view. Assuming that the model has a `self.controller` attribute, you could change your code to be like this:

```
class Model:
    ...
    def display_all_empoyees(self):
        ...
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        self.controller.update_all_employees(rows)
        ...

class Controller:
    ...
    def display_all_employees_data(self):
        self.model.display_all_employees(self.test_str)

    def update_all_employees(self, rows):
        self.view.update_all_employees(rows)
```

Comment: So I should call the "display_all_employees_data()" function in the init method of the View, right? I'm asking because I getting weird error like TypeError: display_all_employees() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @FlyingAxe: if you want to display all employee data when the UI starts up, yes, calling `display_all_employees_data` in the `__init__` of the view makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. I'm assume there is something wrong with __init__ method then. I'll try to figure it out.